# Extract uploaded files from Angularjs to Expressjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I use the following ways to upload file to angularjs, but how can I extract it from express js?

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('file', file);

    $http.post('/api/teams/upload', formData, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success(function(){
        console.log('upload success');
    }).error(function(){
        console.log('upload failed');
    });
```

Comment: Extract it?  It would help if you clarified the problem AND include what you have tried with Express to solve the problem.

Comment: I mean, how to get the uploaded data using sever code? for example: req.data, req.file. As i found that req.body, req.query are also empty.

Comment: It should be available on req.body, are you sure you're listening to POST? meaning yourapp.**post**('your_post_url', funciton req,res...?

Comment: Did you try req.files ? Like explained on http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads

Comment: exports.upload = function(req, res) {
    console.log('req.body');
    console.log(req.body);

Comment: the above are my controller handling, but req.body = {}

Comment: Are you looking for code how to write server side file upload code?

Comment: I think so. What I want is to get the upload formData or files or binary object from angularjs, and store it some where (s3, flickr, local file, etc) via express js server side code.